# Update control value on parent form when all values on subform are changed to a certain value

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, controls, subform

I am currently helping design a business case form in ACCESS 2013 for our department's product managers to facilitate them submit business cases and store data. 
There is one subform on the parent form, which displays all SKUs associated with the business case in datasheet view, as well as their statuses (one SKU might be in stage 1, another in stage 2), and the parent/child form are linked by case ID. That is to say one case ID is associated with many SKUs. What I want to do is to update a field value (case status) on parent form only when all SKU statues are updated to stage 3. If one SKU is stage 3 but another one is in stage 2, then don't update the case status. I googled a lot however there doesn't seem to be a solution I can find online. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @artsylar I haven't done anything yet but only because I have absolutely no idea what to do. It works the other way around, as in update all subform values when a value on parent form changed, but that would not work in this case since I don't want the parent form value to be updated until all subform values are unified to a certain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not save this calculated value to table. Just calculate when needed.

A textbox on subform footer can have expression to count records where stage is not 3.

`=Count(IIf(Stage<>3,1))`

Textbox on main form can reference the subform textbox.

`=IIf([subform container name]!tbxStageCount > 0, "Incomplete", "Complete")`

Comment: Thanks very much that is a clever workaround! I tweaked it a little bit as there are 5 different case statuses stored as combo box options. I added a code on "After Update" on the subform textbox to instruct it to update case status to "complete" when non-stage 3 number count is zero.

Comment: Could a new SKU later be associated with case? Does your code handle that?

Comment: It is very rare to add new SKU to the case but yes I have created logic so the case status will change based on the combination of SKU status.